# Nginx - Stop forcing HTTPS on subdomain

Tags: http, nginx, https

I have a site which is ran with nginx, and with the structure where we have a load balancer, and currently only one web server behind it (currently no real traffic so one web server only).

Anyways, in load balancer nginx config, we forced HTTPS on each request:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.xyz.com xyz.com
    return 301 https://www.xyz.com$request_uri;
}
```

This works fine, but now I want to say "on this subdomain - dev.xyz.com, allow HTTP too and don't do the forcing".

At first, the server_name param was "any", and thought that might be the problem, so I specifically typed the names as in the above samples, and when I type http://www.dev.xyz.com, I get redirected back to the https://www.xyz.com.

Below server block, we have SSL definitions too:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/xyz.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xyzPrivateKeyNginx.key;
    keepalive_timeout   70;
    server_name www.xyz.com;
    root /usr/local/nginx/html;
    client_max_body_size 25M;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    # Add trailing slash if missing
    rewrite ^([^\.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

}

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

it turned out the solution was simple, I only inserted a simple redirect:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.dev.xyz.com
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://xxyyzz;
        }
}
```

Where xxyyzz is:

```
upstream xxyyzz{
    ip_hash;
    server 10.100.1.100:80;
}
```

Thanks anyways!